# Manipulating a byte array

Tags: ruby, string

I have a simple byte array

```
["\x01\x01\x04\x00"]
```

I'm not sure how I can alter just the second value in the string (I know the array only has one item), whilst still keeping the object a byte array.

Something along these lines:

```
["\x01#{ARGV[0]}\x04\x00"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the secret is that you have a nested array:

```
irb(main):002:0> x = ["\x01\x02\x01\x01"]
=> ["\001\002\001\001"]
```

You can index it:

```
irb(main):003:0> x[0][1]
=> 2
```

You can assign into it:

```
irb(main):004:0> x[0][1] = "\x05"
=> "\005"
```

And it looks like what you want:

```
irb(main):005:0> x
=> ["\001\005\001\001"]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Brent, this works vary well, thanks for the elegant solution to my simple little problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `each_byte` string method:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>> str = "\x01\x01\x04\x00"
=> "\001\001\004\000"
>> str.each_byte {|byte| puts byte}
1
1
4
0
=> "\001\001\004\000"
>>
```

Comment: no wait... I don't think I was as clear as I could have been, I just want to replace the second value, it's all part of a byte array, so it will be output as bytes anyhow... perhaps I'm just way off... you may have the perfect answer though. +1

Comment: @jpsilvashy: Would be good if you add the above info into the question. The original one is kinda vague.

Answer (score 1):

It might be less confusing to get rid of the array wrapper.

```
a = ["\x01\x01\x04\x00"]
a = a[0]

a[1] = ...
```

You can always put the string back inside an array:

```
a = [a]
```

Also, technically, it's not a "byte array", it's a single-element Array, with a String object. (And for that matter, strictly speaking, Ruby doesn't really have *Array of Type*; all Ruby arrays are something like `Array of Object` elsewhere.)

Comment: Hey! this is a really great solution also. Makes the string more manageable. Thanks for the insight on Arrays in Ruby as well. +1